# Program with pipes and threads exiting before completion

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pipe, pthreads

I am writing a c++ program with threading and pipes. I am implementing a parallelized algorithm and the idea is that I have a main thread that writes data to child threads. The child thread must read this data, process it, and write back the result to the main thread.

I have stripped down a minimal reproducing, compiling version of the core logic of the communication and commented out the places where I have more code. The program runs and exits without typing out complete. Usually, the last value of i that is printed is between 1 and 9 and the program just terminates without saying anything. I would expect the program to run to completion but I am not getting any errors and the program exits gracefully so I am not sure how to debug.

NOTE: Pipes and Pthreads are mandated from somewhere else and are hard requirements. Please don't suggest a solution to use std::thread or just communicate between threads within the same address space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pthread.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void* func (void* args)
{
    std::vector<int> v = * (std::vector<int>*)(args);
    auto FH = fdopen(v[0], "r");
    char buffer[1024];
    int buffer_len = 1024;
    while (fgets(buffer, buffer_len, FH))
    {
        std::string x{buffer};
    }
    
    // process the result and return it to the parent
    
    return NULL;
    
    
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> *> pipes{};
    std::vector<pthread_t *> threads{};
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        int fd[2];
        if (pipe(fd) < 0)
        {
            std::cout<<"failed"<<std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        int fd2[2];
        if (pipe(fd2) < 0)
        {
            std::cout<<"failed"<<std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        std::vector<int> *pipe_info = new std::vector<int>{fd[0], fd[1], fd2[0], fd2[1]};
        auto F = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
        pthread_t *thread = new pthread_t;
        threads.push_back(thread);
        pipes.push_back(pipe_info);
        pthread_create(thread, NULL, func, (void*) pipe_info);
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
            fprintf(F, "%d", 3);
    }
    
    
    
    // read the data returned from the child threads 
    // using fd2 (indices 2,3) in each pipe in pies.
    // free all allocated memory
    
    
    for (auto thread: threads)
    {
        pthread_join(*thread, NULL);
        delete thread;
    }
    std::cout<<"complete"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `pipe` 2000 times, and each call uses 2 file descriptors, for a total of 4000 file descriptors. The limit on file descriptors is typically about 1000. So I'd start by checking the return value from `pipe`. The return value is `-1` when the call fails.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue. I didn't include it in the minimal version but in my original code, I have the check and it doesn't fail in calling pipe. Also this breaks for very small values of i (usually less than 10). I doubt that the system has less than 20 file descriptors available.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem, and the symptoms you describe seem improbabe. On my system the program prints all the numbers, and does not terminate, but hangs.

The reason is that `pipe()` is not a constructor; `fdopen()` is not a constructor either. The are [c](/questions/tagged/c) interfaces, and they wouldn't close by virtue of leaving the scope. You have to close fds and FILEs manually. You don't do it, and the threads patiently wait in `fgets` for more data or `EOF`. and until `main` close the  writing end of a pipe, there will be no `EOF`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to copy the close calls when writing down a minimal example, but I do have them. I identified the issue to be reusing pipes. Some threads finish processing early and close their pipes. Later calls to pipe() on the loop end up reusing the same descriptors that were closed and this throws SIGPIPE. is there anything I can do to have pipe not reusing descriptors?